Is min(A,[],"all") or min(A(:)) more efficient?
In matlab, which is more efficient, min(A,[],"all") or min(A(:))?
A is a 200x200 matrix. My first idea is that min(A,[],"all") should be faster. Because A(:) will expand the matrix. Is there anyone can interpret these results?

The code is below:
rng(1)
res=rand(200,200);

timeitn= 100; %10000000
tic
for i=1:timeitn
    min(res,[],"all");
end
toc

tic
for i=1:timeitn
    min(res(:));
end
toc


you can also include min(min(res)) in your code. I assume there is no tangible difference between all three approaches.

Please copy-paste the code and results as text into your question. Format text as code using triple fences. See here for reasoning: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

@TinoD I would expect min(min(...)) to be possibly quite a bit slower, since it must do much more work...

@Edric very possible, I tried it yesterday and I noticed a minimal difference in absoluted values (something like 0.05 seconds). But I guess percentage-wise it is a significant increase since other approaches took 0.54 seconds

The nearly half a second time difference you measured is likely caused by other stuff going on in your computer during the measurement. Use timeit for a more precise time measurement.
Or, it could have been caused by the more extensive input argument validation that is necessary to interpret ([],"all") in the first case.
Either way, I don’t expect these two forms to be significantly different in cost. The operation A(:) is essentially free, since no data is copied. This operation simply creates a new array with a different size that points to the same data as A.
